# How to change text alignment with Calibre book editor

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, mobi, editing

I have a book in `.epub` format (I will be converting it into `.mobi` after), and I need to change the text alignment to left everywhere.
I am aware of the *text alignment* feature in the *book editor* but from what I understand it only can change individual selected html elements, where I need to change the text alignment of around 200 full pages of text (not single lines/elements).

Preview: [image]

Does anyone knows a quick way to change the text alignment of all the text? Maybe I can do it during the conversion to `.mobi` but I don't know how.

Comment: You can try with a CSS style like this: `body { text-align: left;}`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do I have to do that individually to all 200 pages? Because that wouldn't be an option for me.

Comment: See my detailed answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CSS style to apply this formatting to all your text:

```
body {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This rule will be applied to *all* your text, so it will affect both regular paragraphs (`<p>` and `<div>`) and headings (`<h1>`, `<h2>` and so on).

If you just want to format "regular" text you could try to apply this styling just to `<p>`'s and see if it is sufficient:

```
p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Of course, if some custom style is already present for these elements, you can just add the CSS properties to the existing selectors.

You must place this code inside the CSS stylesheet. Usually it is named `stylesheet.css` (but it can be different) and you can find it on the left "File Browser" panel under the "Styles" voice

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing which works for me. Put in Styles section of Preferences

```
.bold {
     font-weight: bold 
}
 .calibre {
     display: block;
     font-size: 1em;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 5pt;
     margin-right: 5pt;
     margin-top: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
     text-align: left 
}
 .calibre1 {
     display: block 
}
 .calibre10 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 16px;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre11 {
     display: block;
     height: 16px 
}
 .calibre12 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 2em;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre13 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 16px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre14 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 8px;
     text-align: right;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre15 {
     font-size: 0.75em 
}
 .calibre16 {
     display: block;
     height: 24px 
}
 .calibre17 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 1em;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre18 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 8px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre19 {
     font-size: 1.66667em;
     line-height: 1.2 
}
 .calibre2 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 1em;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre20 {
     display: block;
     height: 3em 
}
 .calibre21 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 4px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre22 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 4px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 1em 
}
 .calibre23 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre24 {
     display: block;
     height: 2em 
}
 .calibre25 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 1em;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 13px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -1em 
}
 .calibre26 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 2em;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0 
}
 .calibre27 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 16px;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 8px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -16px 
}
 .calibre28 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 0.75em 
}
 .calibre29 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 13px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -24px 
}
 .calibre3 {
     font-size: 1em 
}
 .calibre30 {
     font-size: 0.75em;
     line-height: normal;
     vertical-align: super 
}
 .calibre31 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 24px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -24px 
}
 .calibre32 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.125em;
     line-height: 1.2 
}
 .calibre33 {
     display: block;
     height: 8px 
}
 .calibre34 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 20px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre35 {
     display: block;
     height: 20px 
}
 .calibre36 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 64px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre37 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 2em;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-indent: 1em 
}
 .calibre38 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 1em 
}
 .calibre39 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: 8px 
}
 .calibre4 {
     height: auto;
     width: auto 
}
 .calibre40 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 1em;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre41 {
     font-size: 0.75em;
     line-height: normal;
     vertical-align: sub 
}
 .calibre42 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre43 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 3em;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre44 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 1em 
}
 .calibre45 {
     display: block;
     height: 4em 
}
 .calibre46 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 1em;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 4px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -1em 
}
 .calibre47 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 2em 
}
 .calibre48 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 2em;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre49 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 4px;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: -24px 
}
 .calibre5 {
     display: block;
     height: 1em 
}
 .calibre50 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: right;
     text-indent: 1em 
}
 .calibre51 {
     font-size: 1.125em;
     line-height: 1.2 
}
 .calibre6 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 96px;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .calibre7 {
     font-size: 1.41667em;
     line-height: 1.2 
}
 .calibre8 {
     display: block;
     height: 4px 
}
 .calibre9 {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 64px;
     text-align: center;
     text-indent: 0 
}
 .italic {
     font-style: italic 
}
 .mbppagebreak {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 0 
}
```