# Text-align in calibre doesn't work

Tags: calibre

This code:

```
body {
text-align: left;
}
```

doesn't put my text on the left side. Instead I get the block format with spaces of different size between the words. How can I align my text on the left?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text alignment with Calibre book editor](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/how-to-change-text-alignment-with-calibre-book-editor)

Comment: But the change of the CSS doesn't work. :/

Comment: Are you sure that is the only css you have? I suspect there is css that override your body styling, better to check that too.